# Unsupported operand types in form.inc

Tags: forms

OK, this ought to be easy but I've been trying all sorts of ways to get this to work. I'm getting this error in trying to insert a value from the $_SESSION array. I've hunted to determine how to figure out the right key for the field I want to insert this value but must be misreading Drupal's devel module. The form is generated from creating content in a custom content type so there's not a form I've manually set up. Some search results suggest I'm not using a callback in the hook_forms function but this is not used for a $form in a custom module, just the custom content type. The $form_id was derived from using dsm() for the form in question.

```
function re_dashboard_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, &$form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 're_dashboard_research_project_node_form') {
    $form['field_resident_vunid'] = t($_SESSION['vunid']);
  } 
  dsm($form);
}
```

I believe the $_SESSION key is right because I did a dsm() on it earlier. I would have thought that the $form['vunid'] would be correct but I still get this error. It's either a goof I'm not seeing in my Google searches or I have one of these keys wrong. What am I overlooking?, thx, sam

Comment: What kind of variable is $_SESSION['vunid'], is it a fully formed form render array or a value you want to use as a default value for this field?

Comment: +1, and the `vunid` should probably be without a t() call unless you're sure it should be translatable.

Comment: Yes, $_SESSION is an array and the ['vunid'] is the key. In this case, the value is '1234', a String of four characters. dsm($_SESSION) returns an array of three items so I'm positive it's an array.